# How to remove the next element after the first?

Tags: javascript, indexof, splice

The goal was to get every other element of an array that matches the condition I had, but I couldn't get to do that.

So, I set off to try on another example which is found in the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

beasts.splice(beasts.indexOf("bison",beasts.indexOf("bison"+1)),1);
console.log(beasts);
```

I'd expect it to remove the second "bison" from the array and yet it removes the last element which is "duck"...

What could I do here? (granted I might have not yet learned proper syntax for this stuff)

Comment: You are currently searching for `bison1`. It should be: `beasts.indexOf("bison") + 1` and not `beasts.indexOf("bison"+1)`

Comment: var aaa = [1,2,3,4,5]; aaa.splice(1,1); aaa;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your indexOf syntax

```
beasts.indexOf("bison"+1)  // this searches for `bison1`
```

to this

```
beasts.indexOf("bison") + 1
```

```js
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

beasts.splice(beasts.indexOf("bison",beasts.indexOf("bison")+1),1)
console.log(beasts);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your splicing code has only one error, which has been picked up in the comments (`It should be: beasts.indexOf("bison") + 1 and not beasts.indexOf("bison"+1)` as @adiga says).

My guess is, however, that you'd actually like to remove *all* instances of `'bison'` from the list. I may be wrong there, but it's a guess. You can do that with a filter:

```js
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

const updatedBeasts = beasts.filter(beast => beast !== 'bison');

console.dir(updatedBeasts);
```

Comment: Yeah, what @adiga said is the fix I needed! But the end end result I want to get to is to remove every other bison from the list.

Comment: @KarolisVaitkevicius The code I have above will remove _all_ bisons, do you just need to remove 1?

Comment: I need to remove every other after the first. So, remove bison1, bison3, bison5, etc... @OliverRadini

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are going for `bison+1` not `bison` so try this:

```js
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

beasts.splice(beasts.indexOf("bison",beasts.indexOf("bison")),1);
console.log(beasts);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some little mistakes in your code which leads to your output. 
First, of all to remove an element from an array we can use the `splice()` method as follows.

> array.splice(starting_index_from_which_the elements_are_to_be_deleted,
>   number_of_elements_to_be_deleted)

If greater than the length of the array, the start will be set to the length of the array. 
The correct format of your code is:

```
var beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

beasts.splice(beasts.indexOf("bison"),beasts.indexOf("bison")+1);
console.log(beasts);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working way

```
let beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison', 'duck', 'duck', 'bison', "duck", 'bison',"camel", "duck", "duck"];

beasts.splice(beasts.indexOf("bison",beasts.indexOf("bison")),1);
console.log(beasts);
```